# Android Studio Gradle sync error

Tags: sync, android, android-studio, runtime-error

I installed Android 3.3 and upgraded it to version 4.10.1.
Now I'm going to run one of the default activities.
But when it comes to sync the Gradle, it shows me this message:
[image: error message image]
What should I do?
please guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change the version to the version of your Android Studio. Change `4.10.1` to `3.3`

Android Studio 4.10.1 was not released yet in any channel. Even the Android Gradle Plugin, the one you're actually talking about, has not been released yet.